# wrong syntax at http parameter values

Tags: http

The next hyperlink is supposed to give me the users with ids 001 and 002.

```
 http://localhost:9000/users?myIds=001;002
```

Is there a problem with the semicolon? the controller is showing receiving only 001 but not 002.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass multiple values into a single **[`GET` parameter](https://en.ryte.com/wiki/GET_Parameter)**; you have to separate them out using an **ampersand** (`&`):

```
http://localhost:9000/users?id1=001&id2=002
```

Then you can access the IDs with `id1` and `id2` respectively.

If you specifically need to pass a string with a semicolon as a GET parameter, you need to use the **[HTML entity](http://webcheatsheet.com/html/ref_entities.php)** `%3B` instead:

```
http://localhost:9000/users?id1=001%3B002
```

Comment: well, myIds is suppose to get just one value: a string like '001;002' and the controller is expecting that string. Do I need to use some especial char to specify '001;002' as a string value for myIds?

Comment: You should be able to use the HTML entity `%3B` for that. I've updated my answer to cover that.